# Counting Descending numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working on taking an array, lets say : {5,4,3,8,9,8,8,7,6} is my array. My goal is to find out how many sets of descending numbers there are in this array.

So far I've used my code to compare if the number in that index is less than the previous number. This is as far as I've gotten, and it prints out all the values that were smaller than the previous index value.

I'm semi new to java and have worked in python before, so I'm not quite sure how I would store the values that are less than the previous and how many total sets there are

```
public class Descending {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int[] x = {5, 4, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6 };
        countDescents(x);
    }

    public static void countDescents(final int[] xs) {
        int total = 0;
        // start with first index value.
        // Compare to previous index value to see if it is descending.
        for (int i = 1; i < xs.length; i++) {
            if (xs[i] < xs[i - 1]) {
                System.out.print(xs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the total amount of descending sets would be 3 (desired output), those being 5,4,3 & 9,8 & 8,7,6

(The only reason my print statement is at that point in the loop is just to see if it was the right numbers as descending)

Comment: What if you counted the number of times the value goes up?

Comment: @geekygenius what would be my advantage to that vs doing descending numbers? Would it be the same concept?

Comment: The number if times the previous value is greater than the next value plus one is equal to the number of sublists of descending numbers. This solution requires no memory in the loop.

Comment: Also, when do you increment the total?

Comment: Look into using Lists, which are like arrays with flexible dimensions. For your problem you'll likely need a list of list of integers. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Comment: @geekygenius so would I just add to my total the numbers that are less than the previous and call for the length so I would have my total number of sets? I haven't incremented the total yet, since I wasn't sure on how to store the values for when I have a new descending set.... New to Java here

Comment: Are you just trying to come up with a number, or the sublists themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Given you don't need to know the length of the runs, just the number of them, then you are really just looking for how many times a run starts: i.e. an elements is one less than the previous but the same is not true for the previous element:

```
int runCount = 0;
boolean inRun = false;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < array[i - 1] && !inRun)
        runCount++;
    inRun = array[i] < array[i - 1];
}
```

If you are using Java 8 you could do this with an `IntStream` instead of iteration:

```
int runCount = IntStream(1, array.length)
    .filter(i -> array[i] < array[i - 1])
    .filter(i -> i == 1 || array[i - 1] >= array[i - 2])
    .count();
```

It's a bit unclear if you are looking to actually store the descending runs rather than just count them. If you need to know what the runs are then you will need to collect them in a list. Let me know in the comments if you want help with that.